# ogr2ogr manipulating cpu and memories

Tags: ogr2ogr, multithreading

My OGR2OGR command is working very hard and I am kind of satisfied but not as fast as I expected.
What I am doing is Joining a table to a fgdb feature class and save it to another fgdb.
through my mac Activity Monitor, I recognized that it only uses one CPU core.

[image]

It does seem like Geotiff format can use multiple cpu cores but ogr2ogr cannot (or I may be wrong).

How do I use all the CPU cores?